# How to connect to the Redis database with different user?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, redis, predis

I just started learning Redis and do not know how to change the database user. I added a user named **redis** while installing the redis. Here are few questions.

1. How can I add a new user and set the password for that?
2. How can I choose his user for connecting the database?

```html
Redis config file:

[Unit]
Description=Redis In-Memory Data Store
After=network.target

[Service]
User=redis
Group=redis
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/redis-cli shutdown
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target


Laravel config file:

 'redis' => [
        'client' => 'predis',
        'default' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' =>0,
        ],

    ],
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no such facility. Any one connect to Redis can send command to it. So never expose Redis to untrusted clients.

In order to make it safer, you can set a password for Redis (check the `requirepass` directive in `redis.conf`). Then the client has to use the `AUTH` command to do the authentication.

**UPDATE**

Since Redis 6.0, it supports Redis ACL. With this feature, you can set multiple users with different password on different key spaces. Check the [doc](https://redis.io/docs/management/security/acl/) for detail.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using laravel 7 and client select predis, you can try the configuration in config/database.php.
My workspace predis version is 1.1.9

```
'default' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', '6379'),
            'database' => env('REDIS_DB', '0'),

            'options' => [
                'parameters' => [
                    'username' => 'YourName',
                    'password' => 'YourPassword'
                ]
            ]
        ],
```

I hope it helps